# How to open a large CSV file with multiple columns and rows

Tags: csv, large-files, scilab

I'm honestly a novice on scilab.

I need help in opening my csv file.This file is automatically generate by a software in xlsx and I convert in csv.file.  I'm not sure where to start, because it's a large file. I have started with Read.csv and this error message appeared:"An inconsistency was found in the columns"

I put an screenshot [of my File right there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET5Wv.jpg)

Please someone could explain me step by step how to read this file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the xlsreadwrite atoms modules. With it you can directly read xls  ans xlsx files.

Comment: Thank you, But, it'll work even if my file has empty cell and complex disposition ?

Comment: I think so. please try it